# Required and optional arguments in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with using optional and required arguments in a function.

```
def process_data(*stock, currency)
```

With the arguments

```
process_data('IVV', 'QQQ', 'USD')
```

Yields the error "TypeError: process_data() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'currency'"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Anything *after* `*args` can only be addressed as *keyword arguments*. You cannot have positional arguments after `*args`. As is all three of your arguments are collected in `*stock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `*params` in a function *definition* groups all positional arguments as a tuple when that function is called. In order  to catch any extra arguments you'll need to supply them in keyword form; i.e supply their name:

```
process_data('IVV', 'QQQ', currency='USD')
```

You could alternatively specify `currency` with a default value of `USD`:

```
def process_data(*stock, currency='USD')
```

and not need to specify the currency when calling unless you require a different currency:

```
process_data('IVV', 'QQQ')
```

Comment: Thank you, I also discovered that reversing the arguments fixes the problem so the code looks like `def process_data(currency, *stock)`
`

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Python that USD is the currency as it has no other way of knowing how to assign values to your variables:

```
process_data('IVV', 'QQQ', currency='USD')
```